# How should I access this promise result (React, DataStore, AWS Amplify)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, aws-amplify, datastore

Following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrkkNte1onA&t=742s (2:36:48).

I am trying to access a promise that is found in useState value: dishes.

Here is my code on the third (and last useEffect) I query order DataDish (which contains the following info: quantity, orderID, orderDishDishId) with the condition that the orderID equals the order id of the order I'm returning. I set the dishes into a state with .then() but when accessing dishes the Dish data (name of the item, price, etc) is a promise. (See image below)

```
import {Card, Descriptions, Divider, List, Button} from 'antd';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import {DataStore} from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import {Order, OrderDish, User} from '../../models';


const DetailedOrder = () => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    const [order, setOrder] = useState(null);
    const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(null);
    const [dishes, setDishes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        DataStore.query(Order, id).then(setOrder);
    }, [id]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(order?.userID) {
            DataStore.query(User, order.userID).then(setCustomer);
        }
    }, [order?.userID]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!order?.id){
            return;
        }
        DataStore.query(OrderDish, c => c.orderID.eq(order.id)).then(setDishes);
    }, [order?.id])

    console.log(dishes);

    return (
        <Card title={`Order #${id}` } style={{ margin: 20 }}>
            <Descriptions bordered column={{ lg:1, md:1, sm:1 }}>
                <Descriptions.Item label="Customer">{customer?.name}</Descriptions.Item>
                <Descriptions.Item label="Customer Address">{customer?.address}</Descriptions.Item>
            </Descriptions>
            <Divider />
            <List 
                dataSource={dishes}
                renderItem={(dishItem) => (
                <List.Item>
                    <div style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{dishItem.Dish.name} x{dishItem.quantity}</div>
                    <div>${dishItem.Dish.price}</div>
                </List.Item>
            )}/>
            <Divider />
                <div style={styles.totalSumContainer}>
                    <h2 style={{fontWeight: '400'}}>Total:</h2>
                    <h2 style={styles.totalPrice}>${order?.total?.toFixed(2)}</h2>
                </div>
            <Divider />
            <div style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                <Button block type='danger' size='large' style={styles.button}>
                    Decline Order
                </Button>
                <Button block type='primary' size='large' style={styles.button}>
                    Accept Order
                </Button>
            </div>
            <Button block type='primary' size='large'>
                Ready For Pickup
            </Button>
        </Card>
    );
};

const styles = {
    totalSumContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      display: 'flex',
    },
    totalPrice: {
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    buttonsContainer: {
      display: 'flex',
      paddingBottom: 30,
    },
    button: {
      marginRight: 10,
      marginLeft: 10,
      color: 'white',
    },
  };

export default DetailedOrder;
```

The console.log(dishes) returns the folowing in the console:

[image]

I am trying to access the data found in Dish but its a promise and cant figure out how to bring it into state.

I've tried another .then() but I couldn't figure it out (just starting out with javascript). I've read up on async/await but I couldn't understand how to implement it.

Let me know if you might know but need more info. I'm happy to provide whatever is necessary. This is my first question on StackOverflow and it was much harder to formulate a 'good question' than I thought.

Vadim (The guy in the youtube video) does not encounter this problem (2:37:08). I suspect it is because of updates to amplify. But I'm not 100% sure.

Any info would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the api calls to async then you can try the following

```
useEffect(() => {
 
    const fetchOrder = async () => {
       const orderResponse = await  DataStore.query(Order, id);
       console.log('order', orderResponse);
       setOrder(orderResponse)

       // ideally fetch all data here to avoid unnecessary rerenders
       // and check if the response user is different from previous use to prevent refetch of user
        if(orderResponse?.userID) {
         const customerResponse = await DataStore.query(User, orderResponse.userID);
         console.log('order', customerResponse);
         setCustomer(customerResponse)
         
        }

     if(!orderResponse?.id) {
       const dishResponse = await DataStore.query(OrderDish, c => c.orderID.eq(orderResponse.id));
       console.log('dish', dishResponse);
       setDishes(dishResponse)
    }

    fetchOrder();
   
}, [id]);
```

I am hoping this will help you to debug to solve your issue and the write maintainable code.

Cheers