# Why is only the last object re-rendering in ReactJS when setting an array in useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify, datastore

I need to access promise Value that was returned from AWS amplify datastore. I tried using Async/await to access the promise, it didn't work.

[How should I access this promise result (React, DataStore, AWS Amplify)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74650889/how-should-i-access-this-promise-result-react-datastore-aws-amplify)

this was the same problem I was facing and I tried the solution recommended by @Azzy. but it didn't work.

```js
if(orderResponse?.id) {
    const dishResponse = await DataStore.query(OrderDish, (c) => c.orderID?.eq(orderResponse.id));
    console.log('dish', dishResponse);
    setDishes(dishResponse);
}
```

[when I tried this I got the same results. (Dish details were returned as a promise)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtRF5.png)

since it didn't work, Then I used the useState

```js
const [dishes, setDishes] = useState();
```

dishes to map the data to get the objects out of the array so I can access the orderDishDishid values to retrieve Dish data. below is the code used to map and set data in react usestate

`const [orderDish, setOrderDish] = useState([]);`

```js
useEffect (() => {
      dishes?.map((orderdishItem) => (
        setOrderDish(orderdishItem)
      )
    )
},)
```

[here when I console.log(orderdishItem) all the objects are showing in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS4O6.png)

but only the last object is set to the "orderDish" in the usestate
`const [orderDish, setOrderDish] = useState([]);`

when console.log(orderDish)
[only the last object is re rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ2Ct.png)

I want to set all four objects in the useState to access the Dish Details.

please let help me to understand why only the last object is re-rendering. what i have done wrong and how to set all objects in to `const [orderDish, setOrderDish] = useState([]);` using dishes?.map

if you can provide code snippets that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided **your copy of the code, only a snippet you got from another answer I might not be able to help you**, but here is what I think is happening.

If you look at the answer **the whole logic of fetching an order was wrapped within an asynchronous function**:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchOrder = async () => {
    const orderResponse = await DataStore.query(Order, id);
    console.log("order", orderResponse);
    setOrder(orderResponse);

    if (orderResponse?.userID) {
      const customerResponse = await DataStore.query(
        User,
        orderResponse.userID
      );
      console.log("order", customerResponse);
      setCustomer(customerResponse);
    }

    if (!orderResponse?.id) {
      const dishResponse = await DataStore.query(OrderDish, (c) =>
        c.orderID.eq(orderResponse.id)
      );
      console.log("dish", dishResponse);
      setDishes(dishResponse);
    }
  };

  fetchOrder();
}, [id]);
```

If you look at other examples from *aws-datastore* you can see that they wrap their queries within `async` functions just like this shot snippet demonstrates:

```js
async function onQuery(setPosts) {
  const posts = await DataStore.query(Post, c => c.rating("gt", 4));
  setPosts(posts)
}
```

Then they are able to call this asynchronous function like if it were a normal function:

```
<input type="button" value="QUERY rating > 4" onClick={() => { onQuery(setPosts)} } />
```

And that's the same pattern the solution you found uses. It first defines the asynchronous function `fetchOrder` and then calls it.

When you use `useEffect` and `map` on the `dishes` you are performing as many `setOrderDish` as elements the array has so you are effectively putting one in place of the other and provoking as many resets of the state as elements there are. That's why you can only see the last, because the rest of them have been previously there but replaced by the next.

Brief sample of asynchronicity, try them on the browser's console:

```js
// INFO: function that returns a promise
const func = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Promise started')
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Hello World!"), 100)
})

// INFO: function that wraps that promise
const asyncFunc = async() => {
    console.log('Function started')
    const data = await func()
    return data
}

// INFO: how to get the result of the promise
func().then(data => console.log(data))

// INFO: how to get the asynchronous result
const data = await asyncFunc()
console.log(data)
```

I would highly recommend using promises, so I'm guessing here but this could be a solution:

```js
const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState(undefined)
const [order, setOrder] = useState(undefined)
const [userId, setUserId] = useState(undefined)
const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(undefined)
const [dishes, setDishes] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  if (orderId) {
    DataStore.query(Order, id).then(_order => setOrder(_order))
  }
}, [id])

useEffect(() => {
  if (order && order.userId) {
    setUserId(order.userId)
  }
}, [order])

useEffect(() => {
  if (userId) {
    DataStore.query(User, userId).then(_customer => setCustomer(customer))
  }
}, [userId])

useEffect(() => {
  // INFO: I don't get the model completely because it queries the dishes 
  // if the order has no ID. But it would follow the same pattern.
  // Ideally a parent component would leave the customer data and dish data 
  // to child components after fetching the Order (which seems to be key to 
  // render the rest of  it) so the logic would be less cluttered.
})
```